# Unable to detect new TTF font (Nerd Font)

Tags: fonts

I am trying to install a Nerd Font variant to Ubuntu (specifically "DejaVu Sans Mono Nerd Font Complete.ttf" from [Nerd Fonts GitHub repo](https://github.com/ryanoasis/nerd-fonts/tree/master/patched-fonts/DejaVuSansMono/Regular/complete)) for use in my terminal (Kitty, already using DejaVu Sans Mono). I've downloaded this file and copied to it `~/.local/share/fonts`, after which I restarted the terminal and tested to see if it was picked up. Both terminals tested didn't hadn't picked up the new font.

I also tried adding the font to `~/.fonts`, and still not being picked up.

After searching how to install fonts, I've also tried running `fc-cach -fv` after copying to each directory and then checking what is installed with `fc-list | grep Deja`. The font isn't listed. Only fonts in `/user/share/fonts` seem to be detected.

I have also tried installed the font with Ubuntu `font-manager`, but this reports the following error: `Library.vala:162: 2 :: unknown file format :: /home/.../.fonts/DejaVu Sans Mono Nerd Font Complete.ttf`.

Has anyone any experience installing Nerd fonts, or ideas why this true type font isn't being detected?

I'm running Ubuntu Mate 20.04.1.

Comment: The `~/.fonts` directory ought to make it available. Maybe try the `/usr/local/share/fonts` directory.

Comment: ~/.local/share/fonts works for me. Did you run fc-cache or fc-cach, as you wrote?

Answer (score 3):

You are using the wrong font files. Use the fonts that have "Nerd Font Complete Mono Windows Compatible" in the file names.

Copy the files into a subdirectory in `~/.local/share/fonts/`. (`~/.fonts/` is deprecated, but should still work.) Then run `fc-cache -r`.

According to the Nerd Fonts Readme file:

> - Pick your font family and then select from the `'complete'` directory.
>
>   - If you are on Windows pick a font with the `'Windows Compatible'` suffix.
>
>     - This includes specific tweaks to ensure the font works on Windows, in particular **monospace identification** and font name length limitations
>   - If you are limited to monospaced fonts (because of your terminal, etc) then pick a font with the `'Mono'` suffix.
>
>     - This denotes that the Nerd Font glyphs will be monospaced not necessarily that the entire font will be monospaced

---

If the font still does not show up in font selectors, some terminals have a "Show all fonts" option you can try.

[image: Konsole Font Selection]

---

For `kitty`, you need to edit `~/.config/kitty/kitty.conf`. Note that there are no quotation marks around the font name.

```
font_family      DejaVuSansMono NF
```